# How to convert Date in angular to SGT time zone

Tags: angular, datetime, time

I want to set SGT time zone while sending the date from angular to server.
but `effectiveDate` going as `null` to backend

How to set time zone in component level?

```
pipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
date : Date;
this.date = this.form.controls['effectiveDate'].value;
this.vendorForm.patchValue({effectiveDate:this.pipe.transform(this.date,'GMT+8')});
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried & issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

```
new DatePipe('en-Us').transform(new Date(), 'dd:MM:yyyy hh-mm-ss', 'GMT+8')
```

Comment: How to can i send this to backend

Comment: Simply put your 'date' in place of `new Date()`, store it into a var and send. `const newDate = new DatePipe('en-Us').transform('your date', 'dd:MM:yyyy hh-mm-ss', 'GMT+8')`. `newDate` needs to be sent.